# Proving linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $A$ be a non-singular $3\times3$ matrix. 
Then vectors $Au$, $Av$, $Aw$ are also linearly independent.

This is a True/False question, that needs to be proved as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What are your thoughts about this question?  Any guess in either direction?

Comment: I'll gave some hint: $A(au+bv+cw)=0$ iff $au+bv+cw=0$ (why?)

Comment: It might be rude to put it this way, but I really doubt you've been paying any attention to this intro-level class.

Comment: I've been paying plenty of attention to this class, and yes, I'm still having hard times grasping vector spaces. If that looks like I'm not "paying any attention" than so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true. Suppose $c_1Au + c_2Av + c_3Aw = 0$ for some scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$. Then $A(c_1u + c_2v + c_3w) = 0$. Since $A$ is non-singular, this implies that $c_1u + c_2v + c_3w = 0$. As $\{u,v,w\}$ is linearly independent, it follows that $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$, and hence $\{Au, Av, Aw\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!

I hope you won't mind explaining to me a little more since I'm still not sure I'm following.

We already know that c1u + c2v + c3w = 0 since they are linearly independent.
Is this the process of proving it:

c1Au + c2Av + c3Aw = 0 ,
= A(c1u + c2v + c3w) = 0 ,
= A (0) = 0 ,
= 0 = 0 .

Comment: No. We don't know that $c_1u + c_2v + c_3w = 0$. All we know is that $c_1Au + c_2Av + c_3Aw=0$. It so happens that this implies that $c_1u + c_2v + c_3w=0$ - but we need to prove that (as I demonstrated above).

Answer (score 2):

Pre-multiplying by a non-singular(invertible) matrix induces an isomorphism between $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^3$. isomorphisms send linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets, so yeah. The new vectors are independent.

Comment: We still haven't learned the term "isomorphism", therefore I can't follow your answer. Could you explain it differently? Thanks!